# What can somebody do with my IBAN?

Tags: united-kingdom, online-payment, business

I would like to start a business online, which would require people to pay me for service. I am in the UK.
Because of a specific situation I'm in, private bank transfer is one of my only viable payment options (this is not a legal issue as I will be a sole trader) . Obviously that means providing my customer with my IBAN. Is it safe to give this information to people online (privately), and if not, what can they do with this information?
In case it matters, my contact options would be email and social media DMs.

Comment: You probably want to specify your country, otherwise it's not clear what card you're talking about in the context of bank accounts, and what a "sort code" is.

Comment: I am in the UK, and I am not sure whether sort codes are an international thing. It is a string of 6 numbers corresponding to the branch where you got your card from.

Comment: Do they have IBAN in the UK? For international transfers you might also need your bank's SWIFT code.

Comment: They do. I'm not exactly sure of everything I will need as I am asking a safety-related question and whether it is safe to give it out online.

Comment: Usually in Europe you'd be giving out the IBAN for payments, but I'm not certain specifically about the UK

Comment: I did some research and I will need my IBAN.